# x++ equivalent in Lisp?

Tags: function, int, lisp

I want an integer x, that increases by one every time a function is called.

I was told to use (defvar x) to declare the variable, but does this declare it as an int?

And also, is there a Lisp equivalent to x++ (x = x + 1) that I can use at the end of the function?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `(incf x)` is the equivalent of `x++`. Btw, RTFM

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin Actually, `(incf x)` is the equvivalent of `++x`, but if they are used only for the side effect, the differece does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`incf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_incf_.htm) for incrementing:

```
(defvar *call-count* 0)

(defun my-func (...) 
  (incf *call-count*)
  ...)
```

Read up on [`defvar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm); it creates a dynamic variable but does *not* declare its type (use [`declaim`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_declai.htm) for that).

There is no `int` in Lisp, just [`integer`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_intege.htm), whose size is not limited by the standard (there is a smaller `fixnum` size too, but there is no reason to declare this variable's type).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare what type it is. Just set it to a number.

Use the macro `incf` to change the binding to the successor of the current binding.

You don't need to have it as a global. You can have a closed over variable to update. Eg.

```
(let ((call-count 0))
  ;; create my-func in the scope of call-count
  (defun my-func (arg)
    (if (eq arg 'get)        ;; if the argument is the symbol get
        call-count           ;; return call-count
        (progn               ;; else we do first 
           (incf call-count) ;; update the binding to a hight value 
           arg)))))          ;; and then the job, as example it's #'identity


call-count     ; ==> ERROR call-count has not value
(my-func 'a)   ; ==> a
(my-func 'b)   ; ==> b
(my-func 'get) ; ==> 2
```

Comment: It's better to use a global variable. No kidding.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I guess there is no performance differences here? I guess it's easier to have it as a package global but using a closure is more safe against other functions/people altering it directly.

Comment: The `LET` statement prevents such functions to be recognized as a top-level form for the compiler. The call-count gets reset, whenever one loads the file (is that a feature or not?). Common Lisp is generally not so much about information hiding, but having open access to the parts for inspection. Typically I would just use a specially named symbol internally in some application/library symbol package. The function is not extensible - which is usually desirable - you can't easily change the function without resetting the call count.